# OO Conception when having UndoManager and Listeners on a JComponent

Tags: java, swing, undo

When building a GUI in Swing, I'm always stuck with a conception problem that I end hacking in a bad way. I would like to know the good practice about it.

Let's take a simple example.

I have a JComponent on which I'd like to implements undo/redo actions, and some actions that add/remove other components. So, I would start writing :

```
public class MyComponent extends JComponent {
    private UndoManager undo =  new UndoManager();
    public void addComponent(JComponent comp) {
        this.add(comp);//Add the component to the view
        undo.addEdit(new ComponentAddedEdit(comp));//make this action undoable
        fireComponentAdded(comp);//warn the listeners that the action occured
    }
}
```

Then starts the issue. In my `ComponentAddedEdit` I would think of something like:

```
public class ComponentAddedEdit extends AbstractUndoableEdit {
    private final JComponent comp;
    public ComponentAddedEdit(JComponent comp) {this.comp = comp;}
    @Override
    public void undo() throws CannotUndoException {
        MyComponent.this.removeComponent(comp);
    }
    @Override
    public void redo() throws CannotRedoException {
        MyComponent.this.addComponent(comp);
    }
}
```

Of course, it doesn't work because the redo action will create an new Edit to the UndoManager. So I need to create a new method like that:

```
public void addComponentNoUndo() {
        this.add(comp);//Add the component to the view
        fireComponentAdded(comp);//warn the listeners that the action occured
}
```

In the end, just for the "add" action, I end up with 3 methods with similar names : `add`, `addComponent` and `addComponentNoUndo`. If I have more actions, more complex ones, It can become very confusing. So how would you do that ?

Comment: Have you thought about using a memento pattern?

Comment: I didn't, but now that I study this option, I don't see how it could fix the problem. Could you show me how you would write the `undo` with a memento ? IMO you would still need to be able to add a component without firing new edit, which mean that you still need the `addComponentNoUndo` method. The only difference is that that method could become private.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I am not really into swing, so I may not give you a specific implementation answer, but see this [tutorial on memento pattern](http://www.tutorialspoint.com/design_pattern/memento_pattern.htm).

You surely need to tailor it to your needs, but I think this is the way to go.

Try writing your own "state"-class rather than simply using a string.

I you then want to undo something, load the old state. If you do not want the user to be able to undo something, simply do not load the previous state, telling the user that it is not possible. Think about adding a boolean flag "undoable" to your "state"-class.

**EDIT**

something like

```
class state extends JComponent {

   private boolean undoable;
   private JComponent toSave;

   public state (boolean undoable, JComponent toSave, ...) {
      this.undoable = undoable;
      this.toSave = toSave;
      ...
   }
...
}
```

Comment: Thanks, but the problem in this case is that I would need to save the entire state of my object each time, and recreate it completely. I'd rather save only the edits. If I didn't want to recreate the whole state I would need methods very similar to my `addComponentNoUndo`. Your code sample is not the part I couldn't figure out. What gives me trouble is how you would recreate the state and warn the listeners without throwing a new Edit.

Comment: You may also just save the edits as `state`.
`redo` and `undo` would go forwards or backwards in your savedStates history. something like:
`undo: new state (true, this); this = getState (index -1)`
`redo: this = getState (this.index +1)`

while you only save edits in your state class.
(I hope you understand what I mean)

Comment: You could store the edits as `HashMap<K, V>` where you define the changed attributes of your JComponent as Key-Value pairs. Making a `getState` could give you a `HashMap` you can parse for differences in your class.

Comment: I think that everything you are describing is already implemented in the UndoManager. But anyway, my problem would remain because in your `restoreFromMemento` method I would still have to call a method to undo the component addition without firing edit. So I would still need my `addComponentNoUndo` method

Comment: What if you introduce another boolean determine wether it should fire or not?

`boolean fire;
if (fire) fireComponentAdded(comp);`

Comment: This is an option that would work fine. I will just wait because my question was more about the best practice and I would like the opinion of someone more familiar with UndoManager and Swing. Anyway, I keep this in mind and will accept it if I don't get better options. Thanks for your time.

Comment: I think that I hit some methods from sun with a "shouldFire" parameter. I will consider Sun's Java code as an acceptable reference for good practice and happily accept your answer. Thanks.